# how can i make a directory wirtable, from visual studio code?

Tags: python

[image]

> how can i write that in mac ?

```
# path_append.py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/doit/Mymod")
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really asking. You can use `pwd` in the terminal to see the real path of your current working directory. (As an aside, don't use `sys.path.append` ever.)

Comment: Please do not post images of code

Comment: i mean that "c:/doit/Mymod"(window) >> show me a similar example(mac) please